# How can I define global options with sub-parsers in python argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to figure out how to add global option in a sub-parser scenario with pythons arparse library.

Right now my code looks like this:

```py
def parseArgs(self):
    parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parent_parser.add_argument('--debug', default=False, required=False,
        action='store_true', dest="debug", help='debug flag')

    main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    main_parser.add_argument('--debug', default=False, required=False,
        action='store_true', dest="debug", help='debug flag')

    service_subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(title="category",
        dest="category")
    agent_parser = service_subparsers.add_parser("agent",
        help="agent commands", parents=[parent_parser])
    return main_parser.parse_args()
```

This works for the command line `./test --help` and the `--debug` option is listed as global:

```
usage: test [-h] [--debug] {agent} ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --debug     debug flag

category:
  {agent}
    agent     agent commands
```

However when I trigger the agent sub-parser with the command line `./test agent --help` the `--debug` option is now no longer listed as a global option but as an option for the sub-parser. Also it must now specified as `./test agent --debug` and `./test --debug agent` no longer works:

```
usage: test agent [-h] [--debug]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --debug     debug flag
```

What I'd like to be able to do is define `--debug` is global so that it can always be specified for all sub-parsers and appropriately listed as such in the help output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`main_parser` fills in the defaults into `namespace` (`False` for `debug`); if it encounters `--debug` it changes `debug` to `True`.  When it sees the `agent` string, it calls the subparser, passing it the remaining argument strings, and the namespace that it has been using.

Now the subparser does the normal parser things - if fills in the defaults for its arguments, setting `default` to `False`.  If it encounters `--debug` in the remaining strings, it changes that to `True`.  Otherwise it leaves it as is.  Once it is done, it passes the namespace back to the main parser, which then returns it to your code.

So for

```
myprog.py --debug agent --debug
```

`namespace(debug=False)` has flipped from False to True to False and back to True.

This a consequence of sharing the same `dest` for both the main parser (I don't like the use of 'global' in this context), and the subparser.

There was a bug/issue that tried to change the behavior a bit, passing the subparser a 'virgin' namespace, and then somehow merging its result with the main one.  But that produced some backward compatibility issues.  I could look it up if needed.

For now, trying to define the same optional in both the main and subparser   is bound to create confusion for you  and your user.

If I change the parent to

```
parent_parser.add_argument('--Debug', action='store_true', help='debug flag')
```

(no need for default, or the dest if it is sames as the option flag)

the resulting namespace will look like

```
1721:~/mypy$ python stack37933480.py --debug agent --Debug
Namespace(Debug=True, category='agent', debug=True)
```

Or I could define

```
parent_parser.add_argument('--debug', dest='debug1', action='store_true', help='debug flag')
```

and get:

```
1724:~/mypy$ python stack37933480.py --debug agent --debug
Namespace(category='agent', debug=True, debug1=True)
```

Same flag in both places, but different entries in the namespace.  After parsing I could do something like:

```
args.debug = args.debug or args.debug1
```

to unify the two flags.  Your user will see '--debug' regardless of which help asks for.

Sorry if the description is a bit long winded, but I think it's important to understand the behavior first.  Then solutions become more apparent.

In this case the use of a parent doesn't complicate the issue.  I assume you are using it just to add this debug to all subparsers.

Another option is to just define `debug` for the main parser.  Yes, it will be missing from the subparsers help, but you can always add a note in the description.

===================

The subparser definition takes a `prog` parameter.  If not given it is defined base on the main `prog`.

If I add `prog` as:

```
agent_parser = service_subparsers.add_parser("agent",
    prog='myprog.py [--debug] agent',
    help="agent commands", parents=[parent_parser])
```

subparser usage becomes:

```
1824:~/mypy$ python3 stack37933480.py agent -h
usage: myprog.py [--debug] agent [-h] [--debug]
```

or I can add that `prog` to the `add_subparsers` definition

```
service_subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(title="category",
    prog='myprog.py [--debug]',
    dest="category")
```

Check the code for that method to see how it constructs the default usage prefix.  It includes `main` positionals, but not optionals.

http://bugs.python.org/issue9351 - in this patch the original developer thought that users would expect the subparser definition of an argument should override the main parser's values and actions.  You were, on the other hand, expecting the main definition to have priority.

http://bugs.python.org/issue24251  - but the correction proposed in 9351 caused problems for other users.  That's why I think it is better not to define the same `dest` in the main and sub.  It is hard to satisfy everyone's expectations.