# Default value for a subparser option (Python argparse)

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, argparse, subcommand

My program `boiler` uses `argparse` for parsing command line options and subparser `chain` (in fact, I am going to add more subcommands). It should take the option `-t` both for the main option parser and for the subparser.

Example:

```
boiler -t URL chain
```

is equivalent to

```
boiler chain -t URL
```

The subcommand parser's option overrides the global option. For example:

```
boiler -t URL1 chain -t URL2
```

is equivalent to

```
boiler chain -t URL2
```

What is the most elegant way to code this with Python `argparse`?

The thing I am really going to do is describes in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53750697/856090 of the question [Chaining in a command line several tranformations with options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53686523/856090). Take note that the above described is not exactly what I need, but I need to parse a pipeline of subcommands as described there (some of these subcommands may take `-t` option and other options with possible global default).

Example of what I really need:

```
boiler -t URL1 pipe 'chain -t URL2 + chain'
```

Here the first chain of two chains separated by `+` uses URL2 and the second one uses URL1.

Comment: You can define a `-t` for both main and subparser, but give them different `dest`.  That way the default (or value) of the subparser `-t` won't step on the value for the main.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue9351 - is the patch that gave priority to the subparser defaults.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543820/argparse-options-for-subparsers-override-main-if-both-share-parent and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933480/how-can-i-define-global-options-with-sub-parsers-in-python-argparse